# Is there any way to make the below code in one-line

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, methods, one-liner

I am trying a cipher technique (One Time Pad), I got the solution but want to make it one-line. Here's a sample input and output respectively.INPUT(TEXT) = 'HELLO', KEY = 'XMCKL', OUTPUT(CIPHERTEXT) = 'EQNVZ'.

```
def ciphertextFor(text, key):
    cpt = []
    for i in range(len(text)):
        cpt.append(chr((ord(text[i])+ord(key[i])) % 26+65))
    return ''.join(cpt)
    # return ''.join(chr((ord(text[j])+ord(key[j])) % 26+65)) for j in range(len(text)))
```

Comment: so what is the problem with your attempt?

Comment: please provide sample input and expected output. Read [mre]

Comment: assuming that text and key are the same length this list comprehension should work `[chr((ord(text[i])+ord(key[i])) % 26+65) for i in range(len(text))`

Comment: Something like this (untested) would probably do it. I will leave it to your judgment whether it is an improvement over the original code. `ciphertextFor = lambda text, key: ''.join(chr((ord(t) + ord(k)) % 26 + 65) for t, k in zip(text, key))`

Comment: @GiladGreen It tested my solution and it had an error. I was so impatient that I didn't check it. Thanks to Akshay Sehgal , I realised my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with a simple list comprehension directly from your function above -

```
text, key = 'ajshwhsuhe','amchaksheo'

cipher = ''.join([chr((ord(text[i])+ord(key[i])) % 26+65) for i in range(len(text))])

print(cipher)
```

```
'MHGAIDWNXE'
```

Comment: @AkshaySehgal Using `zip` is better though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` to iterate through the chars from input and key at the same time

```
>>> input, key = 'HELLO', 'XMCKL' 
>>> ''.join(chr((ord(x)+ord(y)) % 26+65) for x,y in zip(input, key))
'EQNVZ'
```